# Failed to resolve component: v-content, from Vuetify, and the content of it is not loading

Tags: vue.js, configuration, electron, vuetify.js

I have an Vue.js / Electron App. I'm trying to use a v-content (from vuetify) component in my vue App.vue, but it does not load, and in Electron console I get the following warning, that makes clear why:

```
     runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-content
      If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via 
    compilerOptions.isCustomElement at <App>
```

Others Vuetify components  like v-app-bar and v-toolbar-title worked perfectly...

I'm not sure if Vuetify components can be considered "native" as the warning says, but anyway I did not find how to exclude the component from "component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement". Does anybody knows where to find it?
The previous questions of the same issue posted here doesn't helped me. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109639/vuetify-v-menu-component-not-visible) is the closer of my issue.

My App.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app color ="primary" dark>
        <v-toolbar-title>OwnTime</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content>
        My content
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage"

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    HomePage
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
}
</script>
```

My Main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import { loadFonts } from './plugins/webfontloader'

loadFonts()

createApp(App)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app')
```

My vue.config.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
  },

  pluginOptions: {
    vuetify: {
            // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vuetify-loader
        }
  }
})
```

Comment: Which version of vuetify are you using?

Comment: Hi @A.D . I'm not sure which one is being used. I instaled it usind vue CLI: vue add vuetify. And in my package.json I have in "dependencies":    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.0". But in devDependencies I have:  "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.0-alpha.0".

I'm not sure which of them node uses when I run    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",